# Email users matching properties based on location, price etc

Tags: rules

I'm building a Drupal 7 site that captures users property preferences (location, price range, bedrooms etc.) in the account creation form. I have a property content type that contains fields that match the ones in the user signup form. I'm trying to figure out a way to email users when a property or properties are submitted to the site that match their preferences.

I've watched the Rules framework series on the nodeone site (great tutorials BTW!) and I'm thinking this may be possible using Rules, VBO and maybe the Relation module? So I'm wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction or let me know if I'm crazy for thinking this is possible at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable, may not even need any custom PHP.
What type of fields are location, price range and bedrooms?  Static list of values, or user can enter their own?

Comment: Right now I have it set up so that user can pin their location on map using the Location module & Gmap. The price range and bedrooms are generic CCK integer fields.

Comment: I hit return too fast on that last comment! continued from last...

Right now so they can enter whatever number they want. I could convert it to a list values if needed.

The property nodes have actual street addresses but I'm geocoding them in hope that I can match the users to the properties based on their chosen location on the Google map. (eg. match users that are within 10km of the property).

So ideally a match would happen if the users preferred location was within a certain distance of the property, the number of bedrooms required matched and the price was in their range (+/- $200).